# How do I reopen a view controller by a button?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to program a game.
If someone fails and the 'GameOver' method starts, there will be a button called 'Again?' which will not be hidden anymore.
If someone clicks on this one the viewcontroller which is alreay opened(the game)should load again. Something like `[self viewDidLoad]` or `[super viewDidLoad]` does not work here.
Please help me guys,
Thank you for your answers!
Peace

Comment: either make a method on your viewcontroller to reinitialize itself, or just replace the viewcontroller with a new instance of the view controller

Comment: how do i make a method on my viewcontroller to reinitialize itself?
Thanks

Comment: Well how did u initialize it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your existing viewDidLoad method does all of the required setup, move the setup code to a new method, say setupView:

```
-(void)setupView{
    ...view controller setup code...
}
```

and then call setupView from viewDidLoad to initialize the view:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self setupView];
}
```

and call it again when the 'Again?' button is clicked

```
-(IBAction)againButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    [self setupView];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with setupView?

Comment: setupView should contain all of the code required to initialize your view controller, so that you can call for initialization from the viewDidLoad method and/or any other method that needs to reset the view controller. see the edited response...

Comment: Thank you! the only problem is idk what i have to put in this setupview method

Comment: put all of the initialization code that you've already written into setupView, i.e. anything that is currently in viewDidLoad (other than [super viewDidLoad];) and any other setup code that you called to get the view controller started initially

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
- (void) resetView
{
    //release view
    self.view = nil;
    //force view loading
    [self view];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately a completly black screen appers